# How wait for multiple facebook graph api calls before proceeding in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, callback

I will preface question this with the fact that I am newer to Javascript, and the idea of callbacks is fuzzy despite the research I have done. What I am trying to do is get all checkin information from FB and then send that to a google map where it can all be plotted. I am having a hard time understanding how callbacks can be used to wait for the 3 facebook graph api calls I have.

```
FB.api("me/checkins?fields=place.fields(location,name)&limit=1000", this.passToMap);
FB.api(me/photos?fields=place.fields(location,name)&limit=1000", this.passToMap);
FB.api("me/statuses?fields=place.fields(location,name)&limit=1000", this.passToMap);
```

I understand the passToMap callback is called after the facebook api call is done retrieving the data. But how to I determine when all of these calls are finished? I need to determine this so I know when it is safe to start rendering all the points. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can save each data pieces in a variable so you know once the three call are resolved.

```
var store = {};

// Implement something similar for each api call
function checkinCb( data ) {
    store.checkins = data;
    this.passToMap( store );
}

// Example flow, update accordingly
function passToMap( data ) {
    // If data is incomplete wait
    if ( !data.checkins || !data.photos || !data.statuses ) return;
}
```

To make it cleaner, you could also wrap the `FB.api` calls in a façade who's returning promises you can chain.

In all cases, try googling *JavaScript async flow controls*, it should come up with multiple solutions people use to manage asynchronicity.